# ng-click anywhere on document?

Tags: angularjs

I have this login menu and its show on click but whenever i click its still open. Now i need to implement when user click anywhere on page that $scope.loginOpened = false...(to close that div with login menu)how i can do that? Any suggestion ?
This is an example of login menu:

```
$scope.toggleLoggedIn = function () {
            $scope.loggedInOpened = !$scope.loggedInOpened;
            $scope.languagesOpened = false;
            $scope.loginOpened = false;  
        };
```

EDIT:

```
 <div class="fade-show-hide" ng-show="loggedInOpened" ng-cloak>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_LoggedInPartial.cshtml")
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your view part here.I think you need to use ng-hide for close the login-menu div.

Comment: @satya there is view part

Answer (score 1):

you can use `blur()`

example

```
<input type="text" ng-enter="doBlur($event)">
```

script

```
$scope.doBlur = function($event){
    var target = $event.target;
    if (!$scope.loginOpened){
      // do more here, like blur or other things          
      $(target).blur(function() {
       //do what you want here
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the div you can follow the below process.

```
 <div class="fade-show-hide" ng-hide="loggedInOpened" ng-cloak>
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_LoggedInPartial.cshtml")
     </div>
     <button type="button" id="btn" ng-click="toggleLoggedIn()">Hide div</button>

$scope.toggleLoggedIn = function () {
            $scope.loggedInOpened = !$scope.loggedInOpened;
            $scope.languagesOpened = false;
            $scope.loginOpened = true;  
        };
```

Comment: that is with button but i want when user click anywhere on whole page to hide the div

Comment: @uzhas:For that declare controller inside body part and click event as well.

Comment: im not sure that i understand what u mean because i dont have body part...its partial view?